# What means {{name}} parameter in a API

Tags: php, api

I want to know what kind of parameter I need to send to the API.
The parameter is the one inside {{group_ids}}.

**API DOCS**

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api.newsletter2go.com/newsletters/{{newsletter_id}}/send" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer {{access token returned by OAuth endpoint}} " \
  --data "{
    \"scheduled\": \"2018-08-08T17:02:12+0200\",
    \"group_ids\": [
        \"{{group_id}}\"
    ],
    \"recipient_ids\": [
        \"{{recipient_id}}\"
    ]
}"
```

**PHP CODE**

I am developing it in PHP, so what I understand is that If I want to send "group_ids" and "list_selected". 
I think that {{group_ids}} is an autonumeric array, but I am not sure.

Is this correct?

```
$params = array(
    "group_ids" => array(
        0 => $segment_id
    ),
    "list_selected" => false
);
```

*Note: You can tell me that I should test, but this API has an error that if you send a bad param it will send to the whole contact list instead of reporting an error. That happened.*

Comment: use json_encode($params) to send in curl

Comment: I know how to send it, I do not know what {{group_ids}} means (kind of data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the structure you want in PHP is the following.

```
<?php
$data = [
  'scheduled' => '2018-08-08T17:02:12+0200',
  'group_ids' => [1, 2, 3],
  'recipient_ids' => [10, 20]
];

//Hmm, if on older PHP equivalent to...
$data = array(
  'scheduled' => '2018-08-08T17:02:12+0200',
  'group_ids' => array(1, 2, 3),
  'recipient_ids' => array(10, 20)
);

$jsonData = json_encode($data);
```

Expressed as JSON:

> {"scheduled":"2018-08-08T17:02:12+0200","group_ids":[1,2,3],"recipient_ids":[10,20]}

Rest is just escaping for cURL. Reading your last comment, ouch. No dev server I assume?

Comment: Thank you, it is how I thought. 
No dev server here :(